# python memory limits

Tags: python, memory

I would like to generate a list of the following:

```
L = list(itertools.product('...', repeat=8))
```

the call

```
itertools.product(...)
```

generates about 1'099'511'627'776 elements of length 8 (I know its a big number) but my system has 12Gbit RAM therefore it shouldn't be a problem right?

Is it possible that there is a limitation for each process? I checked with

```
ulimit -a
```

and the

```
max memory size
```

is set to unlimited...

Comment: 12GB RAM is 12.884.901.888 bytes, so you have a lot more data to handle than you can... Also, I assume you did not mean Gbit, as 12 Gbit of RAM would be 1.5GB... I seriously recommend to do some brainwork and solve what you try to do in another way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1,099,511,627,776 * 8 is 8 terabytes. 8 terabytes > 12 gigabytes.

You might consider processing this using the iterator directly, without forcing it all to be evaluated and stored in a list.

Of course any non-trivial processing 1 trillion elements will probably take a long time.

Comment: And python will use more than 8 bytes to store the 8-tuple `('.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.')` so it's even more than 8 terabytes.

Comment: When I simply use a = itertools.product(...) it works why is there no memory capacity?

Comment: `itertools.product(...)` creates an generator, it doesn't create all the elements immediately. It creates one and gives it to you each time you ask for the next element.

Comment: the thing is that I need to access the elements per index so is there any possibility to do that without running out of memeory?

Comment: @user1606657 A generator is an iterator and only stores it's state in memory, not the entire output.

Comment: You can call `next` on it repeatedly for an `index` number of times. Of course if your index is particularly large this will still take a long time.

Comment: dump it all in a database, one item at a time, then you can access it "by index".

Answer (score 0):

It should not be a problem to process the data one after the other, but it might be a problem to collect them all.

If you have

```
prod = itertools.product('...', repeat=8)
```

you can iterate over this object with

```
for item in prod:
    # process item and drop it afterwards
```

which will only consume the amount of memory which is needed.
 But with

```
L = list(prod)
```

all objects will be taken and used and put into the list. This might be quite lengthy...